Rosetta 2 on Linux ARM with vmare fusion 13.5.2
I run Vmware Fusion Pro 13.5.2 on M1.
Using Vmware Fusion, I virtualize a Debian ARM vm. All good.
Now, I just need to run a binary( amd64 only ) on this VM. With UTM and Parallels, it works great as they allow you to mount Rosetta on your linux VM, but I cannot find this basic feature on VMware Fusion. Can it be that they don't support it ??
Because if I do :
./my-amd64-binary

Obviously I get
-bash: ./my-amd64-binary: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

because this should have been ran along with rosetta such as
rosetta ./my-amd64-binary

Thanks

Self answering from : https://community.broadcom.com/vmware-cloud-foundation/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=7165&MessageKey=56524565-0316-46a5-9c79-bdf5c580d50c&CommunityKey=0c3a2021-5113-4ad1-af9e-018f5da40bc0
Fusion doesn't support these hooks that allow Intel apps to run 
in arm64 Linux VMs. It's available only to VMs running under 
Apple's high level virtualization framework. 
Fusion uses the low level Hypervisor frameworks

Alright, sticking to Apple Virtualization Framework with Xcode and Swift then and uninstalling Fusion
